Search codes for finding bidirectional note cues in Microsoft Word
I'm working on an eBook in Microsoft Word (not the ideal method, I realize - but I'm having trouble finding comprehensive guidance on how to directly edit epub files quickly and efficiently).
I'm trying to fix the formatting of the notes, which in epub files are bidirectional hyperlinks - so that clicking on the cue in the main text takes you to the note, and vice versa.
My question is: Is there any way of searching in Microsoft Word for those note cues - analogous to how searching "^f" (without the quotes) will point to all of the footnote cues. I've tried to find comprehensive list of these special character codes, but none of them seem to include this kind of hyperlink character (though I'm not sure what name it would go by in such a list).
Many thanks to anyone who could point me in the right direction...

You're in the right place! Not sure what kind of hyperlinks you are using in this case, but Word supports endnotes which are bidirectional links, similar to footnotes. Perhaps you are using those? You find them by searching for ^e.
